# floating-point math operations output in C++

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

I am trying to right a simple math program, and I am facing difficulty getting correct formatted output.

Here is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14159265358979;

int main()
{
        double a,b,c,d;

        a = cos(30*PI/180);
        b = sin(30*PI/180);
        c = cos(90*PI/180);
        d = sin(90*PI/180);

        cout << a << endl;
        cout << b << endl;
        cout << c << endl;
        cout << d << endl;
}
```

which give the following output:

> 0.866025
>   0.5
>   1.61554e-015
>   1

I tried to use round as follows but round will round all of them

```
cout << round(a) << endl;
cout << round(b) << endl;
cout << round(c) << endl;
cout << round(d) << endl;
```

which gives the following output:

> 1
>   0
>   0
>   1

at last I tried fixed but it is fixed for all

```
cout << fixed << a << endl;
cout << fixed << b << endl;
cout << fixed << c << endl;
cout << fixed << d << endl;
```

Output

> 0.866025
>   0.500000
>   0.000000
>   1.000000

**What I am trying to get is output output like:**

> 0.866025
>   0.5
>   0
>   1

I know floating-point is hard to deal with due to representing the unlimited by a limited storage.

I went through a lot of readings about floating-point numbers but have not find how can I get the required result using only the standard C++ libraries.

and because angles 30 and 90 is just a sample I cannot use different output techniques for each variable.

I would prefer sticking to cout rather than printf as long as possible.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Whats wrong with printf?

Comment: @MartinPerry: how does `printf()` help with the situation? With respect to your question: lack of type-safety and lack of support for user-defined destinations immediately come to mind.

Comment: You are getting a non-zero result where zero is desired because `PI` is not equal to the mathematical constant π. You may want to investigate whether your platform offers the functions `sinpi` and `cospi` which multiply by π internally, so `cos(90*PI/180)` becomes `cospi(90/180)`. For example, on recent OS X and iOS versions, these functions are available as vendor extensions `__sinpi()` and `__cospi()`.

Comment: Thanks all, Nothing wrong with`printf()`, I just wanted to make sure we can solve the problem using `<cmath>` functions. not just re-formatting the output. Unfortunately, I tried @njuffa suggestions, but nothing worked for me with gnu and code::blocks on windows 10. but why do you assume my `PI` is not same as mathematical.I checked `M_PI` which did not worked for me either and found it is the same value. Any way, thanks for help.

Comment: @Shadi well-written implementations of the trigonometric functions `sin`, `cos` use what amounts to (for practical purposes) an infinitely-precise approximation of the mathematical constant π/2, reducing the argument to [-π/4,+π/4]. The numerical discrepancy between your `PI`, or the system-defined `M_PI` (both of which are only accurate to double precision) and the infinitely-precise π leads to the  non-zero result where you would expect zero. FWIW, I am reasonably sure Boost offers `sinpi()` and `cospi()`, maybe check that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the offending output is the one for `c` using scientific notation. If so, you'll need to deal with the values separately: the flexibly format (neither `std::ios_base::fixed` nor `std::ios_base::scientific` is set and the format is equivalent to the use of `printf()`'s `%g` format) will print values in a fashion which represents values with the set precision as best as it can. This approach will use scientific notation when the number of digits needed to reasonably represent the value.

One way to deal with this situation is to explicitly detect "bad" values, e.g., values below some threshold. If you want to avoid checking each output individually you can `imbue()` a custom `std::locale` object with a custom `std::num_put<...>` facet, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

const double PI = 3.14159265358979;

struct num_put: std::num_put<char> {
    iter_type do_put(iter_type to, std::ios_base& fmt, char_type fill, double v) const {
        if (v < 1e-4) {
            *to = '0';
            ++to;
            return to;
        }
        return std::num_put<char>::do_put(to, fmt, fill, v);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new num_put));

        double a,b,c,d;

        a = std::cos(30*PI/180);
        b = std::sin(30*PI/180);
        c = std::cos(90*PI/180);
        d = std::sin(90*PI/180);

        std::cout << a << '\n';
        std::cout << b << '\n';
        std::cout << c << '\n';
        std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

This quick demo also fixed a few unrelated problems:

- do not use `std:endl`: if you mean to flush the stream explicitly use `std::flush`
- `using` directives are bad

Comment: Thank you very much @Dietmar Kühl. your solution works, but it requires advanced techniques. I hoped that there are something simpler and standard that would work with `cout` e.g. more robust `sin()` and `cos()`. Anyway, thanks for the good solution. finally, for the unrelated suggestions, if you have a good reference for C++ IO streams, I would appreciate.

Comment: @Shadi: Nicolai Josuttis's ["The C++ Standard Library"](https://www.amazon.com/Standard-Library-Tutorial-Reference-2nd/dp/0321623215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1489430526&sr=8-1&keywords=nicolai+josuttis) does contain some description which is reasonably good (I'm biased, though: I helped Nico to write the chapters on IOStreams and Locales). Other thank that, there is a book on ["Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales"](https://www.amazon.com/Standard-IOStreams-Locales-Programmers-Reference/dp/0321585585/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1489430627&sr=8-1&keywords=angelika+langer); I prefer Nico's book, though.